# How to add markers on svg image rendered in xamarin forms

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, markers, skiasharp

I am new to xamarin and developing a cross-platform app using xamarin forms PCL way.

I have a map image in svg format. I am using SkiaSharp library to load that image on my UWP application through PCL. I have 1 ListView having names of locations. I want to draw annotation or location marker on image, on click of the respective list view item.
For ex: If I will click on XYZ location the marker will be shown on the particular location.

This functionality can be easily achieved by using any map api or xamarin maps, But my problem is I can't use any map api and have to show location on image only.

Please Suggest any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible the way you are handling the SVG image.

When a map is presented in a vector or raster file, there is usually a header or companion file containing the latitude and longitude of the top right and bottom left of the image. This is then used along with the image to load the map into a mapping plugin. Simply drawing the map using SkiaSharp will  not allow you to determine where a pin should be positioned.

Can you get the map in another format suitable for using with Xamarin Maps?

Comment: Could you please explain how to load map svg image and show pin with xamarin forms and If svg format is not suitable with Xamarin Maps then which format is supported by maps and how to load that particular image as a map using Xamarin Maps.

Comment: I'm not sure if/how you would do this using Xamarin Maps. It is just a wrapper around Google Maps/Apple Maps. I have done this previously using ThinkGeo mapping tools which is designed to load and display files. It is not cheap though. More details here https://thinkgeo.com/mobile

Comment: So is there any alternate way to use any svg image map of a country in Xamarin Forms to perform the same functionality which provides by any map api.

Comment: @TarunAgrawal I also want to implement same functionality. Have you found solution for this?